# Apache ignores my .htaccess files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Apache completely ignores my .htaccess file, no matter what I write in there it does not read it.

- Rewrite mod is enabled
- AllowOverride is set to All

Virtual host: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com

    <Directory /var/www/example.com>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

htaccess file: /var/www/example.com/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^hjalp/$ /index.php?page=help
```

All questions related to this always seem to get solved by either enabling mod rewrite or by changing AllowOverride to All instead of None. But that does nothing for me, and yeah I have reloaded and restarted apache. (Ubuntu 12.10 "Quantal Quetzal" Minimal x64, Apache/2.2.22)

How do I go about solving this problem?

Edit:
I never really found the problem behind this, but a clean re-install (yet again) solved the issues.

Comment: Your config and htaccess look fine so far. What happens exactly? If you have access to the log files, look into the `/var/log/apache2/` directory and see what is requested (`access` files) and what errors maybe happen (`error` files). There's a timestamp in the log lines, where you can relate the access/error messages to the most current request.

Comment: When I try to access /hjalp/ I simply get a 404.The apache errors logs aren't very helpful either, they just say "File does not exist: /var/www/example.com/hjalp"

Comment: Are you sure mod_rewrite is enable?

`ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ | grep rewrite`

Comment: rewrite.load ... So yes, mod_rewrite is loaded according to phpinfo() as well. There must be something I am missing, this is a clean install using the default configuration files...

Comment: Do you have enable mod_alias & mod_userdir? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html#ToC1

Answer (score -1):

Try with

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^hjalp/$ index.php?page=help
```

without a slash it's works for me

Comment: The RewriteRule I have is working in the development environment, this issue is related to Apache I believe.

Comment: Have you try without slash?